# How should i break a loop if scanf get a wrong type? (c)

Tags: c

this is my code... i tried with is nan, with everything i think, also using a string and then convert it to float with atof and strtof, i would stop the loop if the user insert any string in the do while loop, even just make the code nicer would be nice, thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void shift(float* array,char dir,int size);

int main(){
    int n=0,i;
    float *array=NULL,val;
    char dir[20];
    int numeric;
    do{
        printf("Insert a new element for the array ('stop' to stop): ");
        scanf ("%f", &val);
        if(isnanf(val)) break;
        vettore = (float*) realloc( vettore,(++n)*(sizeof(float)) );
        vettore[n-1] = val;
    } while (isnan(val)==0);
    if(n>0){
        printf("In which direction would to shift the array to? ");
        scanf("%s",dir);
        shift(vettore,dir[0],n-1);
        printf("Here is the array shifted to %s: ",dir);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d, ", vettore[i]);
        free(vettore);
    }else printf("You haven't inserted any number! ");
    return 0;
}
void shift(float* array,char dir,int size){
    int temp,i;
    if(dir=='d'){
        temp=array[size];
        for(i=size;i>0;i--) array[i]=array[i-1];
        array[0]=temp;
    }else{
        temp=array[0];
        for(i=0;i<size;i++) array[i]=array[i+1];
        array[size]=temp;
    }
}
```

The code should do something like this:
Insert a new element for the array: 1
Insert a new element for the array: 2
Insert a new element for the array: 3
Insert a new element for the array: 4
Insert a new element for the array: stop
In which direction would you like to shift the array to? (d for right and something else for left) left
here the array shifted to left: 2, 3, 4, 1,

Comment: For one, you should be verifying the result of the actual [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) call. That function has a documented return code for a reason; *use it*.

Comment: I already tried this, and it doesnt work as expected, or at least, when i insert a string the string is assigned to dir, like it skips the "scanf("%s",dir);"

Comment: Your code does not indicate that you have used it....  should be something more like `int return = scanf ("%f", &val);`

Comment: Please translate the queries to English. Can you give examples  of strings that `scanf("%s", dir)` is supposed to parse?

Comment: "enter a new element for the vector ('stop' to end): "

Comment: Thanks davide for the translation and that code :)

Comment: @user14757651, could you translate all the strings in the **question**?
Moreover, I suggest giving an example of an input that is causing an error.
Show an example of the expected/correct behavior.
This would greatly help people understand the problem and provide useful feedback.

Comment: I guess the problem is caused by re-parsing "stop". Just put `scanf("%*s");`before `if(n>0){` to skip this "stop" word. Did it fix the problem?

Comment: well it does fix the problem but the array is all 0 now, why?

Comment: @user14757651 prego :)

Comment: maybe `printf("%d, ", vettore[i]);` -> `printf("%f, ", vettore[i]);` ?
Printing `float` as `int` will generally produce garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was stated in the comment, the function `scanf` returns a number of successfully parsed inputs.

To check if `float` was correctly parsed, just to check if `scanf` returned 1.

```
int ret = scanf("%f", &val);
if (ret != 1) {
   ... complain
   break;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, but as i said, can u check the comments another time?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```
while( puts("Inserire un nuovo elemento del vettore ('stop' per terminare): ") && scanf("%f", &val) == 1) {
    
    vettore = (float*) realloc( vettore,(++n)*(sizeof(float)) );
    vettore[n-1] = val;
}

//Then clear the buffer from the "stop"
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```